# What really makes a matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I consider linear algebra a fascinating tool, that I believe is worth mastering. So, choose a field $\mathbb{K}$, and we start doing linear stuff.
For finite dimensional spaces, when we fix basis on the domain and image, we gain an identification (depending on the basis choice) between linear maps and matrices. When we are talking about endomorphisms on a space $V$, things get really interesting. While looking to the linear map itself you just see things like kernel and image, when you pass to the matrix language you encounter things that **belongs** to the map, but it's difficult to see, like determinant and trace.

But what about being diagonalizable? I don't understand what means this beyond the definition, and it's a surprise to me that every matrix "have" the sum of your eigenvalues (trace) even when it haven't eigenvalues!

And what else have a linear map? In the sense that if two matrix have the same necessary things (determinant, trace, same eigenvalues or lack of them...) then the two matrix are conjugated (represents the same linear map in different basis).

Comment: What are you using as the definition of diagonalizable?

Comment: In the linear map level, there exists a basis of eigenvectors.
In the matrix level, there exists an inversible matrix M such that M^{-1}*A*M is diagonal.

Comment: The answer is not so easy, although it is a standard part of linear algebra.  https://en.wikipediga.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix gives some good answers, including the "minimal polynomial" characterization.  But you are probably better off taking a linear algebra course and learning it properly.

Comment: If two matrices are conjugate, then they have the same eigenvalues.  The converse is not true, e.g. $\pmatrix{0 & 1\\0 & 0}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 0\\0 & 0}$.

Comment: That would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix.

Comment: Any matrix has $n$ complex eigenvalues, so the eigenvalues always exists. If the matrix is real valued, the sum of the eigenvalues will be real (because both $z$ and $\bar z$ will be eigenvalues) and be equal to the trace (which is clearly real).

Answer (score 1):

In short, diagonalizable of a matrix means that the matrix has independent set of eigenvectors that can span the entire space.

There are several ways to decide whether matrix has independent set of eigenvectors that can span the entire space. One is that if matrix has distinct eigenvalues, it will be diagonalizable. Another is that if the minimal polynomial of the matrix has linear factors (all roots are simple), it will be diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Over any field, a criterion for a matrix to be diagonalisable is that its *minimal polynomial*  splits as a product of distinct linear factors.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix is diagonalizable if arithmetic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity of each eigen values is same.Arithmetic multiplicity of a eigen value means number of times that eigen value repeated.Geometric multiplicity of a eigen value means number of linearly independent eigen vector corresponding to that eigen value.